# Laravel - Multi language File name upload

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

We have create a system for a client which is like Vine. The front-end is using Angular and the back-end is using a REST-API built using Laravel. We are storing the vidoes/pictures on Google Storage. Most of the users are located in the Israel and some of them are using hebrew language on their pc's or mobile phones. The problem is when a user uploads a video with a hebrew/arabic file names. I know Laravel has localization but how do I approach this during file uploads.

The upload is very straight-forward and using the laravel's filesystem. Do I translate the video filename to english first? or just convert all video file names to a random name?

Comment: I think it's better to generate random name.

Comment: But you should still store the original file name that it was uploaded with, could come in handy later.

Comment: I think it depends on your future use. If you are going to use the `original filename` again in the future, you can store the file with some random name and map it to the original name somewhere (maybe in a table). If you are not going to use it, you can just generate random name(timestamp is a good one)

Comment: thank you very much for the insights!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest to convert filenames to something like:

```
auth()->user()->id.'-'.time().'.jpg'
```

With this approach, you'll **always** get unique filename.

Another approach is to create separate folder for each user and create filenames based on last inserted ID.